# How can I pause the vim error messages on launch?

Tags: vim

I have an error in a `.vim` file, so when I run the command that loads that error, it flashes errors onto the screen for a ms before I can read them. I'd like to pause this display or lengthen the timeout so that I can read them.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

With `:messages`, you can recall previous (error) messages. (But be aware that Vim only keeps the last 200.)

Comment: Thanks! This works. How can I scroll in the buffer that contains the errors? I notice that I can do `:set cmdheight=5`

Answer (score 1):

Could you redirect stderr?

```
<programname> 2> error.log
```

I guess it depends on your scenario, but that can be made to work.

Comment: I don't think vim writes anything to stderr (by default, maybe there are some flags for non-interactive mode?)